# Characterization of groups with only low-dimensional irreducible (real or complex) representations

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

For a finite group $G$ define $d_K(G)$ as the largest dimension of an irreducible representation of $G$ on a $K$-vector space. I find the case $K=\mathbb R$ more geometrically appealing but I suspect $K=\mathbb C$ has better properties.

It's an exercise to prove that $d_\mathbb C(G)=1$ if and only if $G$ is abelian, so I ask: is there a characterization of groups such that $d_\mathbb C(G)=2,3,\dots$ in terms of group-theoretical properties of $G$? And the same for $d_\mathbb R$.

Let $V_1, \dots, V_r$ be the irreducible complex representations of $G$. We know that $r$ is the number of conjugacy classes and
$$\sum_i \dim(V_i)^2=|G|.$$
So if $d_\mathbb C(G)$ is small, we know that $r$ is large compared to $|G|$ i.e. $G$ has many conjugacy classes.

I include examples of groups with $d_\mathbb C(G)=2$: the dihedral groups, the quaternion group, $S_3$. And the same for three dimensions:$A_4$, $S_4$, $\text{SL}(2,3)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the complex case, a lot of research has been done and is going on. Denote by $cd(G)=\{\chi(1) : \chi \in Irr(G)\}$. Sidney Garrison, a student of Marty Isaacs, wrote his PhD thesis entitled, *On groups with a small number of character degrees* already in 1973. A good starting point is Chapter 12 of M.I. Isaacs' [Character Theory of Finite Groups](https://www.cefns.nau.edu/%7Efalk/classes/511/Isaacs_Character_theory.pdf). You could also google on "cd(G), character degrees, groups". A lot of research is also going into the so-called *character degree graphs* of finite groups to capture the arithmetic structure of $cd(G)$.

**Note 1** (added February 8th). I did not discuss the real characters and their degrees, that is representations over $\mathbb{R}$. However, a real representation can of course be considered as a complex one. If in the bigger field it becomes reducible, then the real degree $\chi_{\mathbb{R}}(1)=2\chi_{\mathbb{C}}(1)$, see also here, the [notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20220125075334/https://personal.maths.manchester.ac.uk/jm/wiki/Representations/CharacterTheory) of James Montaldi.

**Note 2** (this is the solution to Problem (6.8) in Isaacs' book.)

**Theorem** (*Gary Seitz*, 1966) Let $G$ be a group with a *single* non-linear irreducible character. Then $G'$ is an elementary abelian subgroup.

So in this case, $cd(G)=\{1,m\}$ with $m \gt 1$. For the proof we need two lemmas.

**Lemma 1**: Let $1 \lt N \unlhd G$ minimal and assume that $G$ acts transitively by conjugation on $N-\{1\}$. Then $N \cong C_p \times \cdots \times C_p$, for some prime $p$.

**Proof** If two group elements are conjugate, they have the same order. Hence every non-identity element of $N$ has the same order and owing to Cauchy's Theorem, $N$ must be a $p$-group for some prime $p$. The commutator subgroup $N'$ is characteristic in $N$ and so normal in $G$. Hence by the minimality of $N$, $N'=N$ or $N'=1$; however, in a non-identity $p$-group the commutator subgroup is *always* a proper subgroup. In particular, $N$ is abelian and every element has order $p$, that is, $N$ is elementary abelian.

**Lemma 2** Let $N \unlhd G$ with $G/N$ abelian. Then each of the cosets of $N$ is a normal set (closed under $G$-conjugation).

**Proof** Since $G/N$ is abelian, $G' \subseteq N$. Let $gN$ be a coset of $N$ and $x \in G$, then for all $n \in N$ we have $x^{-1}gnx=g(g^{-1}x^{-1}gx)(x^{-1}nxn^{-1})n=g[g,x][x^{-1},n^{-1}]n \in gN$.

Note that normal subsets of $G$ can always be written as (disjoint) unions of $G$-conjugacy classes.

Now let's prove the theorem.

Since $G$ only has one non-linear irreducible character, it follows (see I.M.Isaacs, *Character Theory of Finite Groups*, Corollary (2.7) and (2.23)(b)) that the number of conjugacy classes of $G$ equals $1+|G:G'|$. On the other hand $G=G' \cup g_1G' \cup \cdots \cup g_rG'$, a disjoint union of the cosets of $G'$ and by Lemma 2 each of the cosets are normal subsets, so each of them is a union of at least one $G$-conjugacy class. But $G'= \{1\} \cup (G'-\{1\})$ consist of at least $2$ conjugacy classes. Since there are only $1+|G:G'|$ conjugacy classes, this means that each of the non-trivial cosets must itself be a full conjugacy class and $G'=\{1\} \cup (G'-\{1\})$ represents its disjoint split into exactly two conjugacy classes! It also implies that $G'$ is a minimal normal subgroup, since each non-trivial $N \unlhd G$ with $N \subseteq G'$, contains at least one non-trivial $G$-conjugacy class, but this cannot be a non-trivial coset since then $|N| \geq 1+|G'|$. And if $G'-\{1\} \subset N$, then $G'=N$. The theorem now follows from Lemma 1.
**Note** In the case above $G$ is solvable and in addition $G'$ is the *unique* minimal subgroup of $G$.

**Remarks**

- Gary Seitz actually classified the groups $G$ having only one non-linear irreducible character. They are isomorphic to either 
  (i) $|G| = 2^k$, $k$ is odd, $G’ = Z(G)$ and $|G’|=2$, or

  (ii) the group of all affine transformations $x \mapsto ax+b$, $a \neq 0$, on a field of order $p^n \neq 2$.
- For far reaching generalizations, for example when is assumed that the irreducble character degrees only takes *two* values, see Chapter $12$, Character Degrees, of Isaacs' book *Character Theory of Finite Groups*.
- Gabriel Navarro, together with Silvio Dolfi classified all finite groups with only one non-linear irreducble $F$-character, where $F$ is an algebraically closed field, with $char(F) \neq 0$, see Comm. in Algebra $2012$.
- In 2013, Xiaoyou Chen, and Jiwen Zeng proved that groups with one non-linear irreducible *Brauer* character are solvable, see International Mathematical Forum, Vol. 8, 2013, no. 13, 627 - 631, HIKARI Ltd, [www.m-hikari.com](http://www.m-hikari.com).

Comment: I'm leaving this comment mostly for my own future reference: a group character is the trace of the representation so $\chi(1)$ is the trace of the identity, so it equals the dimension of the vector space. This 2005 paper (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869305000323) has a good summary of the state of research at the time and the papers that reference it on mathscinet are worth reading.

Comment: Yes excellent idea! Indeed Moretó, Malle, Navarro, will be authors that you will find in these areas, amongst others!